# Rails - ActionController::UrlGenerationError No route matches missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm getting the above error in my Rails app when attempting to implement the edit function to a Comments MVC process.

This is the views code where the error is arising -

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<% if user_signed_in?  %>
      <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_comment_path(@event, comment), remote: true %></p>
      <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button",
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
      <% end %>
```

This is the comments controller code -

**Comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def create
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.create!(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id


        redirect_to @event
    end

    # GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit
        respond_to do |f|
            f.js 
            f.html 
        end
    end

    def update


        respond_to do |format|
            if @comment.update
                format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
                format.js   { }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end



    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:event_id, :body)
    end


end
```

Here are my routes - [image]

I have comments set up as a nested route for events so the route path is correct. I've tried a few different variations on this as trial and error but I'm still getting errors. I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face but I need help from a different set of eyes. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: try `link_to "Edit", edit_event_comment_path(event_id: @event.id, id: @comment.id)`

Comment: TL;DR but probably the params hash has `:event_id` or `:comment_id` instead of `:id`

Comment: In which file you are rendering `_comment.html.erb` partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, if you are not looping `@comments`,

**`comment` should be `@comment`**

```
<% if user_signed_in?  %>
      <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_comment_path(@event, @comment), remote: true %></p>
      <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [@comment.event, @comment],
                  method: :delete,
                  class: "button",
                  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
 <% end %>
```

Also, change your edit action to,

```
   def edit
        @event = @comment.event
        respond_to do |f|
            f.js 
            f.html 
        end
    end
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work - its trying to point to an id but I can't figure out why.

Comment: can you paste your routes file?

Comment: Just added it above.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Could this be connected to the arguments being passed through the simple_form ?

Comment: This is what I have there - <%= simple_form_for([@event, @event.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>

Comment: No, the main form for comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144828/discussion-between-sravan-and-mike-whitehead).

Comment: try changing it to,  `<%= simple_form_for([@event, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>`